# Error logging using Elmah - applications are not using Form Authentication

Tags: elmah

I am referring this : http://haacked.com/archive/2007/07/24/securely-implement-elmah-for-plug-and-play-error-logging.aspx

Just asked :

My question is what about those who are not using form authentication and just using Custom-Authentication, Authenticate site visitors by Sessions etc. By allowing all registered members mean to invite any one who is registered with site.

Any response will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but my best guess is you wish to restrict access to elmah.axd without using forms authentication. There are some ways to accomplish this.
If you have access to the IIS box and you can setup an extra 'site' the advice found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/basicauthen.aspx) might do the trick.